# SSRS 2012 csv export - dynamic column header name

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-csv, ssrs-2012

I need to export my SSRS report to csv format. Issue I am facing is that few column header names change with country code (parameter) and I want to show the same name in my exported csv. I have gone through other related questions and topic, specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105220/ssrs-conditionally-hiding-columns-based-on-parameter-values-csv-export-ignore) one. It suggested that there is a work around by setting data value to null. I have tried this by adding columns and hiding these based on country code, along with setting data value to null for that dataset field. But it did not work. I still get the hidden column in my export, with no values in it.

Can someone confirm that this workaround works or is there any other way apart from creating different reports for each country?

**UPDATE: (added report screenshot and description for clarification)**

Based on apporoach I have taken,
I need to only show Column 'Town' for Country A and only 'Suburb' for Country B. This is easily done by hiding columns based on Country Parameter( and works fine for EXCEL export), but when exported to CSV, both columns are exported.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415330/ssrs-2008-r2-bug-still-dynamically-hiding-column-or-tablix-and-exporting-to-cs) link which is similar to what I have been trying to figure out and looks like there is no solution which can be achieved using only one report.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you need. Also, can you show your dataset query. In the past I've simply renamed columns in the dataset query by dumping the result first into a temp table, renaming the column and then selecting from the temp table. However depending on what you need to change and when there might be simpler solution.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Sorry for the delay, I have updated question with screenshot and description. Dataset is quite straightforward and brings these columns from tables (NULL for column which is not applicable for specific country).

Answer (score 0):

According to this post

[MSDN Social: Hide CSV columns conditionally in SSRS report](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5fecdaf0-7c79-4573-bbdd-9b675568438c/hide-csv-columns-conditionally-in-ssrs-reoprt-rdl?forum=sqlreportingservices)

> The XML and CSV renderers use the DataElementOutput property to
>   control visibility. We can select which item we want to hide in the
>   report, and set the “DataElementOutput” property with value “NoOutput”
>   to work around the issue.

> Alternatively, we can add below expression to control the item’s
>   visibility. Please refer to the expression below:
>   =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="CSV",True,False)

This, incidentally, is the second answer in the thread that you posted. That answer  links to the following article which explains how to do exactly what you need

[Hide/Show Items Dependant On Export Format](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/)

**UPDATE**

It appears that you cannot programmatically set `DataElementOutput` for CSVs. However, according to this post [SSRS - Programatically controlling the DataElementOutput property](https://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver/feedback/details/431073/ssrs-programatically-controlling-the-dataelementoutput-property)

```
in RS 2005 / 2008, you should be able to get the desired effect by adding a filter on the tablix directly (in addition to the visibility condition):

Filter expression: =(Parameters!DataPeriod.Value = "DAY")
Filter operator:    =
Filter value:     =true

Thereby, for the cases where the tablix is not visible, you are also filtering out all the data.
```

You may be able to show/hide country specific columns this way instead.

Comment: DataElementOutput property can not be set dynamically. If I set it to "NoOutput", it will never export that column to csv. I need to do it dynamically based on a CountryCode parameter. =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="CSV",True,False) doesn't work for CSV export. It does work for Excel.

Comment: Hi @twoleggedhorse, are you suggesting that I create two tablix with structure for each country and filter out data based on country because filter works on rows and not columns.

Comment: I think that is probably the only way to get what you want @AB_87. Either that or use bcp coupled with a stored procedure but that is a different solution to what you requested

Comment: Hi @twoleggedhorse, I am facing another problem with two tablix. CSV export uses textbox name as output column name, with two tablix in same report, I can not have same name for two textboxes and so can't have same output column name. Looks like I will have to create separate report for each country. :(

Comment: Sorry about above comment. My bad, It will work by renaming  DataElementName property. This value can be same for two textboxes so my export should work.

Comment: With two tablix, I am getting getting header from hidden tablix in CSV export. Apparently, there is no solution except creating separate reports. Updated question with the link I found with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to do this in SQL. I'm not sure how you determine which Countries require the town to be returned and which require the suburb to be returned but here's a couple of approaches that hopefully cover your scenario.

In either case, the idea is to return the town/suburb data in the same column and then an additional column that will contain a a caption that we can use as the column header.

a. Only one of either the town or suburb column in your table is populated. In this case it's pretty simple.

```
SELECT 
    Country 
    , ISNULL(TownOrCity, StreetSuburb) AS TownSuburb
    , CASE WHEN TownOrCity IS NULL THEN 'Street-Suburb' ELSE 'Town-City' END AS Caption
FROM myTable
```

b. You know upfront which Countries require what and you can pass a parameter in to get the correct column. In this example we'll use a parameter called @TS and pass in either a `T` or and `S`

```
SELECT 
    Country 
    , CASE @TS WHEN 'T' THEN TownOrCity ELSE StreetSuburb END as TownSuburb
    , CASE @TS WHEN 'T' THEN 'Town-City' ELSE 'Street-Suburb' END AS Caption
FROM myTable
```

Whichever approach we take you will end up with a simple table

```
Country    TownSuburb    Caption
Testland   TownA         Town
Testland   TownB         Town
Testland   TownC         Town
```

In you report, you don;t need to do anything except make the town/suburb column caption an expression something like `=FIRST(Fields!Caption.Value)`

That's it, the report is now nice and simple and should export without any issues.

**UPDATE to method**:

```
--
-- Dump data into a temp table
--

SELECT 
        Country 
        , CASE @TS WHEN 'T' THEN TownOrCity ELSE StreetSuburb END as TownSuburb
    INTO #t
    FROM myTable
--
--rename the column
--
DECLARE @NewColumnname sysname = CASE @TS WHEN 'T' THEN N'Town-City' ELSE N'Street-Suburb' END
EXECUTE tempdb..sp_rename  N'tempdb..#t.[TownSuburb]', @NewColumnname, 'COLUMN' 
--
-- finally get the result
--
SELECT * FROM #t
```

Comment: Hi @alanSchofield,  CSV export does not consider column header of the tablix for headers in the export. It uses Textbox name or DataElementName (if value is provided) for header value in export. So, using Caption for column header name won't work for CSV export.

Comment: Hi @AB_87, I've modified the answer, apologies that I had overlooked the CSV part, as important as it was!

Comment: I don't think I can have a SSRS dataset with a stored proc returning dynamic column header. Even if it is possible, is it a good practice?

Comment: You can, I do it a lot. As for good practice? If the performance is acceptable I don;t see the issue. I'm just trying to give you simple options.Feel free to ignore them.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample or a link to how I can have dataset with a stored proc having dynamic column header? I have never done it and actually can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Apologies, I'm mistaken about using them in SSRS (that's what 18hr days do for you!). Sorry to have misled you.

Comment: No worries. Thanks anyway for taking time to look into my issue.